# How to use LuisRecognizerMiddleware to call Luis for every incomming message

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have successfully implemented LUIS from Microsoft's samle [CoreBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot). However in my implementation I want LUIS to check the intent score for every incomming messages. To achieve this it looks like I have to use `LuisRecognizerMiddleware`, but I couldn't find any examples of how to implement it. I don't want to copy-paste my LUIS-code that's working in every steps in my waterfalls in all my dialogs.

So my main issue here is how to implement `LuisRecognizerMiddleware` instead of `LuisRecognizer` which I'm using right now to call LUIS for every message from the user.

Thanks in advance for help.

Here's my relevant code for LUIS:

**BotRecognizer.cs**

```
public class BotRecognizer : IRecognizer
{
    private readonly LuisRecognizer _recognizer;

    public BotRecognizer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var luisIsConfigured = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration["LuisAppId"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration["LuisAPIKey"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]);
        if (luisIsConfigured)
        {
            var luisApplication = new LuisApplication(
                configuration["LuisAppId"],
                configuration["LuisAPIKey"],
                "https://" + configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]);

            _recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication);
        }
    }

    // Returns true if luis is configured in the appsettings.json and initialized.
    public virtual bool IsConfigured => _recognizer != null;


    public virtual async Task<RecognizerResult> RecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);


    public virtual async Task<T> RecognizeAsync<T>(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        where T : IRecognizerConvert, new()
        => await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync<T>(turnContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

**Cognitive models > ContactDialogBot.cs, generated from my ContactDialogBot.json file**

```
public partial class ContactDialogBot: IRecognizerConvert
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text;

    [JsonProperty("alteredText")]
    public string AlteredText;

    public enum Intent {
        cancel, 
        Hjelp, 
        None, 
        Products
    };
    [JsonProperty("intents")]
    public Dictionary<Intent, IntentScore> Intents;

    public class _Entities
    {
        // Simple entities
        public string[] produkt;

        // Instance
        public class _Instance
        {
            public InstanceData[] produkt;
        }
        [JsonProperty("$instance")]
        public _Instance _instance;
    }
    [JsonProperty("entities")]
    public _Entities Entities;

    [JsonExtensionData(ReadData = true, WriteData = true)]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties {get; set; }

    public void Convert(dynamic result)
    {
        var app = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactDialogBot>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
        Text = app.Text;
        AlteredText = app.AlteredText;
        Intents = app.Intents;
        Entities = app.Entities;
        Properties = app.Properties;
    }

    public (Intent intent, double score) TopIntent()
    {
        Intent maxIntent = Intent.None;
        var max = 0.0;
        foreach (var entry in Intents)
        {
            if (entry.Value.Score > max)
            {
                maxIntent = entry.Key;
                max = entry.Value.Score.Value;
            }
        }
        return (maxIntent, max);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs in ConfigureServices() method**

```
var LuisAppId = "";
var LuisAPIKey = "";
var LuisAPIHostName = "";
var luisApp = new LuisApplication(LuisAppId, LuisAPIKey, LuisAPIHostName);
var luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApp);
// Register LUIS recognizer
services.AddSingleton<BotRecognizer>();
```

**In one of my dialogs, StartDialog.cs**

```
protected readonly BotRecognizer _luisRecognizer;
public StartDialog(BotRecognizer luisRecognizer)
        : base(nameof(StartDialog))
    {
        _luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;

        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));

        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
        AddDialog(new ProductDialog());

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                ChoiceStepAsync
            }));

        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
if (luisResult.TopIntent().intent == ContactDialogBot.Intent.Products && luisResult.TopIntent().score>0.8) {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ProductDialog), null, cancellationToken);
        }
}
```